# How to tell Eclipse java Formatter (Ctrl + shift+ F) to stop delete white spaces

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I want the formatter to stop deleting white spaces in declaration fields

This is what the formatter does when I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
[image]

and this is how I want it to be(the alignment of the values should be kept):

[image]

I just don't find where to change it in Formatter settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In eclipse 3.7 it works this way (Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter):

[image]